# save a web scaping result into a CSV or excel file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do a web scraping test for a website that sells cars, so I need to grab the cars info and store them in a CSV or an excel file. I want each info to be stored in the desired column, for example:  car name; car price, millage...
my final code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(adress.content, 'html.parser')
title=soup.h1.text
Price=soup.find("div",class_="value details-price-value").get_text()
vin=soup.find("div",class_= "value details-vin-value").get_text()
car_info=[
]
car_info.append({"price":Price})
car_info.append({"title":title})
car_info.append({"item vin":vin})


with open('cars.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(car_info)
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the current code?

Comment: yes, the saved list doésnt fit into the CSV columns I want.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. so far is working, but still another problem of data being repeated in the CSV file
[data title and price are getting repeated for each car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDx0Z.png)

code:

```
    url =input("enter site:")
car_info=[]
#def requisting():
adress = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(adress.content, 'html.parser')

title=soup.h1.text
Price = soup.find("div", class_="value details-price-value").get_text()
vin = soup.find("div", class_="value details-vin-value").get_text()


car_info.append(title)
car_info.append(Price)
car_info.append(vin)
info=['title','price','vin']

print(car_info)
with open("newcars.csv", 'a', newline="")as nc:
    wr = csv.writer(nc)
    wr.writerow(info)
    wr.writerow(car_info)
```